# How to handle user input errors

Tags: c, data-structures, error-handling, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct vector
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct vector *array;
double length(struct vector*);

int main()
{
    int num,i;
    double xin;
    double yin;
    double zin;
    char buffer[30];
    char buffer2[30];

    printf("Enter number of vectors:");
    fgets(buffer, 30, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num);

    array = malloc( sizeof(struct vector) * num);

    for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter x y z for the vector:");
        fgets(buffer2,100,stdin);
        sscanf(buffer2, " %lf %lf %lf", &xin, &yin, &zin);

            array[i].x = xin;
            array[i].y = yin;
            array[i].z = zin;
    }

    for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
        printf( "Vector:%lf %lf %lf has a length of %lf\n", array[i].x, array[i].y, array[i].z, length(&array[i]));
    }
}


double length(struct vector* vec)
{
    return sqrt( (vec->x * vec->x) + (vec->y * vec->y) + (vec->z * vec->z) );
}
```

Ok the above code is almost finished it asks user for number of vectors then it asks user for the values of those vectors it then will calculate the length and print it out correspondingly.

I am trying to get some error checking in here but I cannot seem to get it...I looked up every possible return value for fgets and sscanf I just cant seem to get it

Defensive features

FIRST printf-------input should only be a single number greater than 0 and EOF should return a message like `printf("enter a number--bye!")` so I tried

```
while( sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num) ==1 && num > 0 )
```

but it still works if something like 3dadswerudsad is entered

also when the user is entering the 3 values for the vector if anything at all other than 3 doubles are entered for a vector the program should terminate with a message so I tried

```
while( sscanf(buffer2, "%lf %lf %lf", &xin, &yin, &zin) ==3 )
```

but it doesn't check for these incorrect inputs!!

I am going crazy

Comment: Your sscanf is working as expected. You've told it to scan for %d - any decimal number. Since the entered string starts with `3`, sscanf will find that 3... Plus, your sscanf for the longs has a space at the start of the pattern...

Comment: You should read a new line if the current line is not valid input, perhaps in a `while` loop.

Comment: so there is no way to get around the line starting with a number?

Comment: You can always take a two-step approach: Scan a string with `%s` instead of a number, then verify whether it's a valid number by testing this string with `strtol`. (`strtol` provides you with a pointer to the last character after the parsed number, which should be `'\0'` for a valid number.)

Comment: I don't understand how to do all of this error checking I don't know why but it is harder than structures which I just learned.

Comment: 0) `i<=num` --> `i<num`, `char buffer2[30];` --> `char buffer2[100];`

Comment: @MarcB a scanf format string should have a space at the beginning.  that space causes the scanf to consume any leading white space.  I.E. to skip over leading spaces, tabs, newlines.

Comment: why does everyone on this website assume that I have been coding for 43 years, I mean it took me 12 hours NON-STOP coding to write this code it is 6:53 am here and not a single person has gave me any form of information that I can comprehend

Comment: The code should always check the returned value from scanf, fgets, malloc (and the related families of functions) to assure the operation was successful.  Such checking (and range checking of numbers, when the range is important) is all part of defensive programing.  The code should always expect the user to input trash (or the OS to trash to 'hickup').

Comment: suggest using getline() rather than fgets(), as getline() can handle any length of input (automatically).  Just remember to pass the resulting returned value to free() after the call to sscanf()

Comment: @Superman I have been coding for every bit of those 43 years, so perhaps I forget the learning curve of a beginner.  However, regarding the 12 hours...  Most projects I work on take thousands of man hours to implement, test, document.  You will get much faster as the concepts/capabilities become 'second nature' to you such that you think about coding problems in terms of the language

Comment: Ok that is reassuring and also thank you for the help I understood it all and I will remember it in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

- compiles cleanly
- shows several examples of error checking

The posted code raised a compiler warning about reaching end of non-void function without a return statement (warnings need to be corrected).
To see all the warnings, enable all the warnings when compiling for `gcc`, use parameters: `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`

BTW: kudos for properly declaring the struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct vector
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct vector *array;

// prototypes
double length(struct vector*);

int main()
{
    int num,i;
    double xin;
    double yin;
    double zin;
    char buffer[30];
    char buffer2[30];

    printf("Enter number of vectors:");
    if( NULL == fgets(buffer, 30, stdin) )
    { // then fgets failed
        perror( "fgets for num vectors failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    if( 1 != sscanf(buffer, " %d", &num) )
    { // then sscanf failed
        perror( "sscanf for num Vectors failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, sscanf failed


    // add validation of num here


    if( NULL == (array = malloc( sizeof(struct vector) * num) ))
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for num Vectors failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful


    for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter x y z for the vector:");
        if( NULL == fgets(buffer2,100,stdin) )
        { // then fgets failed
            perror( "fgets for vector values failed" );
            free(array); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fgets successful

        if( 3 != sscanf(buffer2, " %lf %lf %lf", &xin, &yin, &zin) )
        { // then sscanf failed
            perror( "sscanf for vector values failed" );
           free(array); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, sscanf successful

        array[i].x = xin;
        array[i].y = yin;
        array[i].z = zin;
    } // end for

    for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
        printf( "Vector:%lf %lf %lf has a length of %lf\n",
                array[i].x,
                array[i].y,
                array[i].z,
                length(&array[i]));
    } // end for

    free(array); // cleanup

    return(0);
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Two problems. See BLUEPIXY's comment under the question. Also,will your code solve the issues that the OP has?

Comment: the concern the OP has raised about extra characters in the input has no effect on the operation of the OPs code.  This example simply shows how to perform error checking.  Infact, the OP has already handled the indicated problem by the use of fgets and sscanf.

Comment: I know. But OP wants an input like `2xyz`(suppose for the first `fgets`) to stop the program after showing an error message. Also, you haven't fixed the two problems I told you in my first comment.